# Factory Pattern - Javascript code - function not to be enumerated

Tags: javascript, object

1. I am trying to use the Factory pattern to create a Person object in javascript. While doing this I am trying to set the property of a function to non enumerable while creating the object. But that does not seem to take effect , please can you tell me why it is still enumerating the function property.
2. In the defineProperty call, when I pass only the function name I get a error stating that printPersonDetails  is undefined. I have to pass obj.printPersonDetails to make it work.

---

```
function createPerson(name, age ,sex){
var obj = new Object();
obj.name = name;
obj.age = age;
obj.sex = sex;
obj.printPersonDetails = function(){
console.log("Name: "+ obj.name + " Age: "+ obj.age);
}
Object.defineProperty(obj,obj.printPersonDetails , {                
    writeable:false,
        enumerable:false,
        configurable: false
    });

return obj;
}
var person1 = createPerson("salman", 29,"M");
var person2 = createPerson("rahman", 59,"M");
var person3 = createPerson("sarah",  19,"F");

//person1.printPersonDetails();
//console.log(person1)

for(prop in person1){
console.log( prop +"->" + person1[prop])}
```

## Output

```
C:\dev\javascript>node constructorpattern.js
name->salman
age->29
sex->M
printPersonDetails->function (){
    console.log("Name: "+ obj.name + " Age: "+ obj.age);
    }
```

Comment: `for(prop in person1)` is creating a global variable, which you should almost always avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong:

```
obj.printPersonDetails = function(){
  console.log("Name: "+ obj.name + " Age: "+ obj.age);
}

Object.defineProperty(obj,obj.printPersonDetails , {                
  writeable:false,
  enumerable:false,
  configurable: false
});
```

Right:

```
function printPersonDetails(){
  console.log("Name: "+ this.name + " Age: "+ this.age);
}

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'printPersonDetails' , {                
  writeable:false,
  enumerable:false,
  configurable: false,
  value: printPersonDetails
});
```

BUT, what I think you really want to do is put the utility function on another object.

JavaScript has built-in support for keeping functionality off object instances: the prototype (although this does not solve the `for..in` issue).

So instead of:

```
var obj = new Object();
```

you could use:

```
var obj = Object.create({ printPersonDetails });
```

And then instead of `for...in` you could use `Object.keys` to avoid seeing the property.

The other approach is to keep the `printPersonalDetails` function on another object entirely (which is probably what I would do).

**Edit:**

The following is merely food for thought and not a recommendation:

```js
var DEFAULT_PROPERTIES = {
  name: null,
  age: null,
  eyeColor: null,
  sex: null,
};

function personFactory(options){
  return Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_PROPERTIES, options);
}

function personPrinter(person) {
   document.write("Name: "+ person.name + " Age: "+ person.age);
}

var person = personFactory({ name: "salman", age: 29, sex: "M" });
personPrinter(person);
```

Comment: Hi Ben, when you say "The other approach is to keep the printPersonalDetails function on another object entirely (which is probably what I would do)." - can you please provide a code snippet to illustrate this?

Comment: *"JavaScript has built-in support for this: the prototype."* No. Being on the prototype has **nothing** to do with whether a property is enumerable, and in fact your example (which relies on ES2015 syntax) would create an **enumerable** property that would show up in `for-in` loops on objects created via `createPerson`. You *could* create a prototype object with a non-enumerable `printPersonDetails`, but it would rely on `this`, which is typically what people are trying to avoid with things like `createPerson`.

Comment: I know. I am making the distinction between own and non-own properties (not enumerability).

Comment: I have clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's just not how you use `Object.defineProperty`. Here's an example:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "printPersonDetails", {
    value: function(){
        console.log("Name: "+ obj.name + " Age: "+ obj.age);
    }
});
```

`Object.defineProperty` accepts various flags (`writable`, `enumerable`, `configurable`) which default to `false`. So by *not* doing `enumerable: true` we've made the property referring to the function non-enumerable.

Here's a complete `createPerson`, which uses `defineProperty` for the function and object initializer syntax for the rest of the object:

```js
function createPerson(name, age ,sex){
  var obj = {
    name: name,
    age: age,
    sex: sex
  };
  Object.defineProperty(obj, "printPersonDetails", {
    value: function(){
      console.log("Name: "+ obj.name + " Age: "+ obj.age);
    }
  });
  return obj;
}

var person1 = createPerson("salman", 29,"M");
for (var prop in person1) {
    console.log(prop + "->" + person1[prop]);
}
```

---

Side note: There's virtually never any reason to use `new Object()`. Just use `{}`.

Comment: Thanks Crowder.. Thanks for the tip to use  {} instead of new Object().